# Applying time-shifts

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the array **r**, with dimensions [N,m], where **N** is a time index, and **m** the number of elements in a network. Consider that each of these **m** elements connect to each other, but the influence of element **i** in element **j**, take some time to occur, i.e., there is a delay between each connection given by the delay matrix **delayMat**, with dimensions [m,m].

Said that, I have the following problem: I want to create a matrix [m,m] with the values of the array **r** but with the proper time-sifts (delays) applied following **delayMat**. One way to do that is with:

```
delay  = n - delayMat
drate = np.zeros([m,m])
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(m):
        drate[j,i]=r[delay[j,i],i]
```

Where, **n** is the actual time index, drate the matrix with the delayed values of **r** for each connection. This works, however, it is extremely slow depending on **m**. Is there any way to do this on numpy in a more optimal manner?

Sample code (the actual code needs to read a lot of data so it is unpractical to post it here):

```
import numpy as np 
delayMat = np.random.randint(1,195,[30,30]) 
rate = np.random.normal(0,1,size=(4,1000,30)) 
n = 1000 # current time index 
delay = n-delayMat
drate1 = np.zeros([30,30]) # delayed variable
drate3 = np.zeros([30,30]) 
for pre in range(30): 
    for pos in range(30): 
        drate1[pos,pre]=rate[0,delay[pos,pre],pre] 
        drate3[pos,pre]=rate[2,delay[pos,pre],pre]
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want help vectorizing the loop? Because the larger problem needs more info.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if it is possible to do it without the for loop, for instance, this is the same piece of code done in matlab:

```
      delaynow=i-delay;
      %for rates from L2/3e
      dprov=squeeze(rate(1,delaynow,:));
      dprov=dprov.*blockmatrix;
      [~,~,dprov2]=find(dprov);
      drate1=reshape(dprov2,Nareas,Nareas);
      ```

Comment: No need for a loop. What is `delay` (or `delayMat`) exactly? Is it integers? Can you provide a *runnable* example?

Comment: delayMat is an matrix of integers,  representing the number of steps (time) for the value of r[j,n] to reach r[i,n].

r[i,n] = f(r[j,n-delayMat[i,j]])

Comment: So can you make an example that has small samples of all the input values?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60821543/edit) the question. Do not post code or important information in comments.

Comment: Thank you for that. Could you make the dimensions match up? And verify that it runs correctly when you paste it into your IDE?

Comment: Because it looks like you added another dimension and a new variable, removed a previous one, and the code is not quite right. Try to keep it minimal. Working simulation is important. I don't need to know exactly what your project does.

Comment: Sorry, it is working now, actually, the first dimension makes no difference because it is fixed for drate1 and drate2.

Answer (score 2):

Replace both `for` loops with:

```py
drate1=rate[0, delay, np.arange(30)]
drate3=rate[2, delay, np.arange(30)]
```

Comment: Yup. `np.arange(30)` would be a little more efficient, but not as golfy

Comment: Thanks, Here you go ;)

Comment: Thank you very much!